# Update Telegram link preview programmatically

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I have a bot which creates messages including some urls provided by users.
Telegram creates link previews for those urls. The previews are cached.

Sometimes the content of the url changes, then the preview provided by Telegram is outdated. So I need to update the link preview provided by Telegram.

Telegram link previews can be updated using https://telegram.me/webpagebot. But according to Telegram Bot API, a bot can't talk to another bot to avoid infinite loops. So opening a chat between my bot and webpagebot to request the update is not an option.

How could I force the update of a link preview from my bot? Is there some http request, API, or whatever to do it programmatically?

Comment: what do you want to achieve? 
What does your bot do?

Comment: You can build a userbot using the Telegram MTProto library. There isn't an official and elegant way to do that

Answer (score 0):

You may add a randomly generated variable to the end of the link, so Telegram looks a link as a new link, like this:

Suppose a old link is like:

```
https://example.com/offers/106-tatasky-recharge
```

If you change `og_image`, title, meta description of this page, then use the above link as:

```
https://example.com/offers/106-tatasky-recharge?t=18121980
```

I think, it solves the problem.